# Прокси/обертка для замены undefined на null

Tags: javascript

С сервера приходит "разреженный" json вида

```
[
    { a: 1, b: 2 }, 
    { a: 2,       c: 3 }, 
    {       b: 2, c: 3 }
]
```

т.е. массив объектов, в каждом из которых могут быть свойства `a`, `b`, `c`. Список свойств заранее известен, и он достаточно большой (около 40 штук).

Заполненность каждого элемента достаточно малая (2-3 свойства).

Выражение

```
data[0].c
```

возвращает `undefined`. Нужет какой-то способ заставить его возвращать `null` (т.к. есть куча уже написанного кода, который ожидает именно `null`).

Желательно решение, работающее в IE8+. 
`__defineGetter__` умер не родившись, Harmony Proxy не поддерживается до Edge.

Писать некрасивый код, который шел бы по списку объектов и выставлял все 40 свойств у каждого в `null` не хотелось бы.

UP: речь идет не о каком-то хитром хаке ради замены семантики `undefined` на `null` во всем приложении. Цель - сэкономить на сериализации, чтобы избежать передачи пачки бесполезных данных с сервера. Потому что никакая семантика не оправдывает передачу

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, 
 x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, 
 x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, 
 x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, 
 x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, 
 x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, 
 x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, 
 x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, 
 x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, 
 x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, x : null, 
 },
```

вместо `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`. Сервер знает о существовании свойства, и о том, что оно - `null`, клиент знает о существовании свойства, и о том, что оно `null`. Соответственно, "переписать" - не решение.

Comment: Что мешает серверу по схеме расширить объекты? типа `$.extend(true,{a:null,b:null,x:null,y:null},{a:1,b:2});`. Имхо, придуманное решение, даже если его и можно реализовать, будет с подводными камнями... Например, кто-то в один прекрасный момент будет ожидать undefined, а там будет null... или наоборот.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попытаться использовать решение на базе прототипов.

Основная идея -- установить в качестве прототипа каждого из передаваемых объектов объект, содержащий значения по умолчанию (те самые поля с `null`). Раз нужна поддержка IE8+, то решения на базе `Object.create`, `Object.setPrototypeOf` и `__proto__` не будут работать без полифилов. Зато, можно использовать обычную функцию-конструктор и не боятся за кроссбраузерность.

Вот пример реализации:

```
var ObjWrapper = function(obj) {
    // Поскольку объект разреженный, этот цикл будет иметь
    // небольшое число итераций.
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            continue;
        }
        this[i] = obj[i];
    }
};

// Мы можем использовать всего ОДИН объект в качестве прототипа.
// Это позволяет экономить память, не занимая ее кучей null-свойств
// каждого обернутого объекта.
ObjWrapper.prototype = {
    a: null,
    b: null,
    c: null,
    d: null,
    e: null
    // Задание null-свойств можно оптимизировать с использованием цикла,
    // хотя это уже детали.
};

var obj = new ObjWrapper({a: 'test'});

console.log(obj.c); // выведет null вместо undefined
```

При использовании такого подхода нужно иметь в виду два момента:

1. Конструкция `obj.hasOwnProperty('d')` выдаст `false`, если оборачиваемый объект не имеет свойства `d`. В ряде случаев это может быть критичным.
2. Все равно придется использовать цикл, при десериализации массива и оборачивать каждый его элемент.

Answer (score 2):

> есть куча уже написанного кода, который ожидает именно null

Переписать. Потому что `undefined == null` не просто так.

Comment: я знаю почему `undefined == null`, но конкретно в этом случае это не решение проблемы. сейчас объекты приходят целиком, с null во всех свойствах. хочется сэкономить на сериализации. скажем, надо потюнить клиентскую десериализацию json в объекты так, чтобы для некоторых, заранее известных свойств, задать null по умолчанию.

Comment: И да, в этом конкретном случае, семантически правильное значение - `null`. Т.е. свойство у объекта есть, значение у него есть. Переписать везде проверки на `undefined` - было бы неправильно. потому что `undefined == null` не просто так (

Comment: @PashaPash, надо поменять `=== null` на `== null` и всё. Ну и `switch`, хотя что там делать null'у?

Comment: используется пара сторонних шаблонизаторов. я не уверен как они отреагируют на undefined, а проверять полным ретестом приложения не хотелось бы. т.е. скорее всего просто оставлю `undefined` и поменяю код, но вдруг есть более безопасное решение. ну и опять же, не хотелось бы ломать семантику. хотелось бы подстелить соломку.